# Angular 1 component binding not evaluating parent controllers variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem where I can't seem to get the value of a property on the scope of the controller where I use my component, so if I just type a number in as the property I get the expected result but trying to do something like `$ctrl.val` will give me undefined inside my competent but `3` will give the right result. Does anyone know why this is happening?

I've got a component like this:

```
function RatingController() {
    let vm = this
    this.$onInit = function() { 
        console.log("rating: ", vm.rating)
    }
}

export default {
    bindings: {
        rating: '='
    },
    controller: RatingController,
    template: `
     <span>{{ $ctrl.rating }}</span
    `,
}
```

And then I initialise it like this:

```
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <star-rating rating="main.rating"></star-rating>
 </div>
```

The above will always have rating as undefined in my component however doing this will give the expected result

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
    <star-rating rating="3"></star-rating>
 </div>
```

MainCtrl:

```
export default function CakeController(requestCakes, $routeParams) { 
    let vm = this
    requestCakes.getOne($routeParams.id).then((res) => {
        //compose objects together

        vm = Object.assign(vm, res.data)
    }) 
}
```

Comment: Can you show `MainCtrl` code?

Comment: @BartekFryzowicz I've added the MainCtrl code to the above. The ratings property is getting set as part of the return value from a promise. Now I'm thinking the problem could be that the component is being initialised before the promise is returned which would explain the behaviour. Is there a way to update the component once the new data is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind wrong property in your component. You try to bind `rating` in component config but your component attribute is called `heartrating`

## Answer update

`main.rating` value is not defined yet when component is initialized (your Main controller loads data asynchronously). Try using `$onChanges` hook instead of `$onInit`. Additionally, you should use one-way data binding (use `<` instead of a `=`) because `$onChanges` hook is called called whenever one-way bindings are updated (according to Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)) and genreally 2-way data bindings are not recommended when using components

Comment: Thanks for looking Bartek, that was actually a typo on my part that isn't reflected in the actual code. Must've been a mistake I put in when I mooed the code over here to ask the question.

Comment: That's perfect thanks for helping me work through this problem! For the sake of completeness the binding is `$onChanges` you've given a type as `$onChange`

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help. As for hook name you're right, it was just a typo - fixed.